# Message queue topic "inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus" is not configured after place order. Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, inventory, place-order, reservations

recently reinstalled magento v2.3.0 and after place order get Message queue topic "inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus" is not configured. No success page/no refresh card/ But get order) How to fix it?

Comment: I had the same problem on a fresh install of magento 2.3.0, I solved it by updating magento to 2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you confirm that this module exists: module-inventory-indexer?
   If not, do composer update to get this module

composer require module-inventory-indexer
or
composer update

bin/magento setup:upgrade

2. This file is readable vendor/magento/module-inventory-indexer/etc/communication.xml?
   If not fix permissions